# React router dom show common component in one case and hide in another case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom

I am trying to have a common `Header` component in my route when the user opens `'/'` or `'/details'` route. Also, I don't want to display this common `Header` component when the user opens `'/menu'` route.

Here is my code:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Header />
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/details">
      <Details />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/menu">
      <Menu />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

In this case, I see the common `Header` component even when I load `'/menu'` route which is not what I intend to do. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This component  `<Header />` is in your global level where you define Routes, so its visible to every component. What you can do is define a layout for every page rather than this approach , like in home do like :

```
render() {
    return(
       <div>
          <Header />
             { this.props.children }
             /* anything else you want to appear on every page that uses this layout */
          <Footer />
       </div>
    );
}
```

and in menu you can remove the header :

```
render() {
    return(
       <div>
             { this.props.children }
             /* anything else you want to appear on every page that uses this layout */
          <Footer />
       </div>
    );
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I was looking for a more react-router-dom based solution. Do you think react-router-dom supports such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

The components within each `<Switch></Switch>` is rendered depending on the path of the `<Route>`. In your code, you've made two `<Switch></Switch>` components. The first will render `<Header />` regardless of the path entered (as you haven't defined it as a `<Route>` with a `path` prop). Then, the second switch will also "execute" and check which path it should render. In any case, both `<Switch></Switch>` components will run, with the first always rendering the `<Header />` component.

A solution could be to render the `<Header />` component only when you match a particular path. This can be done if you add it as another `Route` like so:

```
<Route path={['/', '/details']} exact component={Header} />
```

See details [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/path-string-string)

Usage would be like so:

```
<Router>
  <Route path={['/', '/details']} exact component={Header} />
  <Switch> 
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/details">
      <Details />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/menu">
      <Menu />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here, you can use the `<Route>` outside of the switch so it displays inclusively with the rendered result from the `<Switch></Switch>`